# Recommendation required RESTful web services on Linux

Tags: rest

Looking for a recommendation of which framework/web server to go with on Linux. The idea is to build database backed RESTful web services.

I know Java, c++, c# (irrelevant I guess on linux) and C. Okay with developing in any of those.

Comment: C# can be used quite easily on Linux.  See http://www.mono-project.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/implementing-rest/wiki/ByLanguage) is a table of frameworks that have varying degrees of support for REST and the languages they use.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would go with Ruby 1.9.2 + Rails 3

they're fun and you get to learn something new

ubuntu specific install guide: http://web2linux.com/installing-rails-3-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx/

official RoR intro: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: I'd love getting into RoR, actually.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [RESTx](http://restx.org). It is multi lingual: You can write code in Java, Python (server-side JavaScript coming soon). RESTx is specifically a platform for the creation of RESTful resources and web services. It is NOT a traditional application framework. DB backed web services are actually a specialty of RESTx: You identify the reusable components you want (in this case a JDBC capable DB access component), and then just configure it through the RESTful API or by filling out a small form in a browser. As a result, you get a new RESTful web service, which encapsulates the query you specified when creating the new resource.

I'm the lead developer on RESTx, so if you have any questions, please contact me or visit our forums.

Comment: sounds intenresting. I'll definitely give it a spin.